# How can a bot react to its own message(s)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on my own bot right now and it should end up performing more functions. But for the start it should react to its own message(s). However, this does not seem to work, since an error occurs again and again.

***I keep getting the following error:***

```py
Ignoring exception in command create:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\PythonCode\DiscordBot\method2.py", line 15, in create
    msg = await bot.send_message(message.channel,embed=createEmbed)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'"
```

I don't know what the problem is and was not able to finde a solution.

**My code looks like this:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'pp!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is now active and logged into {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.command()
async def create(ctx):
    createEmbed = discord.Embed(title='When would you like me to remind you?', description=':regional_indicator_a: Every 10 minutes\n:regional_indicator_b: Every 30 minutes\n:regional_indicator_c: Every hour')
    emojis = ['\n{regional indicator a}', '\n{regional indicator b}', '\n{regional indicator c}']
    msg = await bot.send_message(message.channel,embed=createEmbed)
    await bot.add_reaction(msg, '')
```

Comment: You need to read the error message.  You are trying to call the method `send_message` which is not available in the class `commands.Bot`  You need to review the documentation.

Comment: Keep in mind the discord.py API has been rewritten twice since the inception of the library. You'll need to remember that in case you're reading an old tutorial that uses functions which no longer exist

Comment: Ohhhh! I feel so stupid. Thank you RufusVS, Silvio Mayolo, and Dominik. It finally works now. :)

Answer (score 0):

As **RufusVS** mentioned in the comments: `send_message` is not part of the class `commands.Bot`. Instead we send the embed with `await ctx.send()` and then react to it by defining the message that you sent.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def create(ctx):
    createEmbed = discord.Embed(title='YourTitle', description='YourDescription') # Embed
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=createEmbed) # Define the message that the bot sends
    await msg.add_reaction("YourReaction") # Add your reaction
```

*Please also have a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) again.*